# Python mirrored string function

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I'm trying to develop a function `mirror()` that takes a string and returns its mirrored string but only if the mirrored string can be represented using "mirrored" letters in the given string.

For example,

```
>>>mirror('vow')
'wov'
>>>mirror('wood')
'boow'
>>>mirror('bed')
'INVALID'
```

That is, a mirrored `b` is a `d`. The letter `e` does not have any mirrored equivalent.

So far I've started with this

```
def mirror(s):
    return str[::-1]
```

How can I extend this to work for whole words?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: create a list of letters that are invalid when mirrored. Check each letter in your reversed string to see if it is in your invalid list: For letter in reverseString: if letter in invalid: return 'Invalid'. I'm thinking time complexity would be be O(n).

Comment: mirror of 'wood' shouldn't be `boow`?

Comment: @Christian the mirror of 'wood' is actually boow!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, you should have a dictionary that stores the mirror image of every character.

```
mirrored = {'b': 'd', 'd': 'b', 'v': 'v', ...}
```

So, for every string that we need to produce a mirror of, you should check that every character in the given string has it's mirrored value in the string itself.

```
given_string = input()
valid = True
for char in given_string:
    if not mirrored[char] in given_string:
        valid = False
        break
if valid:
    # generate mirrored string
```

The reversed string approach you are using is right. Just add above check & you'll be on your way to generate mirrored strings!

Another way to do this, would be using a simple Python hack of `for`...`else`

```
given_string = input()
valid = True
for char in given_string:
    if not mirrored[char] in given_string:
        break
else:
    # generate mirrored string
```

Comment: I suggest using `for`...`else` structure here.  It eliminates the need for a `valid` flag.  See http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops

Comment: Nice suggestion. Though, the `for`...`else` structuring is not that much intuitive & rather confusing at times. But, it differs from person to person. Thanks.

Comment: @SimonT Hope you got why `dict.get()` would have been wrong. :)

Comment: Yes, I misread the code.  `dict.get` wouldn't have been correct since some letters deliberately have no match.

Comment: Thanks Ashish! using the dictionary was actually what i should've done in the first place. it worked!

Answer (score 1):

You can look up the replacement characters in a generator expression as you iterate over the string (in reverse). You can reassemble characters into a string with `str.join`. I suggest using the "Easier to Ask for Forgiveness than Permission" idiom to handle invalid characters (don't check up front if the character is valid, but instead use `try` and `catch` statements to handle the exception raised if it is not).

```
def mirror(s):
    mir={'b':'d','d':'b','o':'o','p':'q','q':'p','v':'v','w':'w','x':'x'}
    try:
        return "".join(mir[c] for c in reversed(s))
    except KeyError:
        return "INVALID"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea about iterating through the given letters in reverse order.  However, you cannot necessarily just give each letter itself as its own mirrored version.  An example would be `b` and `d`, which are mirror versions of each other.

The simplest way if you're learning to program would be to use a `for` loop to move backwards through the given letters, and use some `if` statements for each letter to determine the mirrored letter (if there is one).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def mirror(s):
    mir = {'b': 'd', 'd': 'b', 'o': 'o', 'p': 'q',
           'q': 'p', 'v': 'v', 'w': 'w', 'x': 'x'}
    if not set(s).issubset(mir.keys()):
        return 'INVALID'
    return ''.join(map(lambda x: mir[x], s[::-1]))
```

Here use `set` to judge whether the chars in str `s` is valid or not.

Answer (score -1):

```
def mirror(lst):
  return lst + lst[-2::-1]

print(mirror([0, 2, 4, 6]))
```

Comment: This outputs `[0, 2, 4, 6, 4, 2, 0]`, but what OP wants is to find a string whose glyph sequence is a graphical mirror of the glyph sequence of the incoming string (using some reasonable default typeface not actually mentioned in the question).